New Raspberry plant dying
I bought three berry bushes from Home Depot About four weeks ago. A red raspberry, a blackberry and a golden raspberry. I also a few black roots from the nearby Canyon. So far the one I pulled from the canyon by far has the most growth healthiest the golden raspberry has definitely grown, but the bottom growth looks pale yellow and doesn’t look very good. The blackberry from Home Depot looks pretty healthy and has had some minimal but pretty slow But the red raspberry has continued to decline. Any ideas Blackberries are doing OK and not the raspberries?

H, welcome to the site.  It depends on where you are, what the climate is, what the soil is like and how well it was watered.  You are really asking for opinions.

You might be looking at the greenhouse plant acclimating to real life. Bring back the raspberry to Home Depot for full refund up to a year.

Consider the source, Consider the conditions any plant sold at that source has experienced before you bought it.

Well, your first problem is that you purchased nursery plants are a place that sells construction material. Shop at plant nurseries, not box stores, and support locally owned businesses.
